# std::stoul() takes a long time when input buffer is a very large char*

Tags: c++, performance

I have a char* buf that is 1024^3 (1G) in size. It contains newline delimited hex numbers (`7fefdfff7\n7fefdfff8\n7fefdfff9\n7fefdfff\n7fefdfffb`) and I am trying to read and parse each one of them.

My first approach was:

```
int buf_length = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
char *buf = new char[buf_length];
std::size_t numchars = 0;
for (int offset = 0; offset <buf_length; offset += numchars) {
        unsigned long tmp = std::stoul(&buf[offset], &numchars, 16);
        process(tmp);
}
```

but each iteration of the loop took an unusually long time. It went much much faster once I switched to the following:

```
int buf_length = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
char *buf = new char[buf_length];
std::size_t numchars = 0;
for (int offset = 0; offset <buf_length; offset += numchars) {
// omitting size of the string below does not affect performance much
        std::string s(buf, 9);
        unsigned long tmp = std::stoul(s, &numchars, 16);
        process(tmp);
}
```

It seems that in the first case stoul() processes until the end of the buffer each time but cannot explain why. Could you help me understand what is happening here and why is the performance so different in 2 cases?

Comment: In an input like `7fefdfff7\n7fefdfff8\n7fefdfff9\n7fefdfff\n7fefdfffb`, where is the null terminator? At the end, right? So `&buf[offset]` is going to make one big mother of a `string`. And it's gonna make it over and over and over, a little smaller every time as the loop works it's way through the buffer.

Comment: So many questions! Are all numbers in the input the same size? Do you know exact size of your buffer? Can you split the work into multiple threads? Is `unsigned long` 4 bytes on your system? Because the example you gave `7fefdfff7` is wider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::stoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) takes a `const std::string&` and not a `const char*`. That means that a `std::string` is constructed from your null terminated string, needing to copy every character.

You can instead use [`std::strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) which takes `const char*` arguments directly:

```cpp
for (const char* ptr = buf; ptr < buf + buf_length;) {
    unsigned long tmp = std::stroul(ptr, &ptr, 16);
    process(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::stoul` isn't the villain here. It's the `std::string` parameter of `std::stoul` that is killing you.

`std::stoul(&buf[offset], &numchars, 16);` will take `&buf[offset]` and turn it into a `std::string`, reading from `&buf[offset],` until it finds the null terminator at the end of that gigabyte-long `char` array. That's one big `string` and it takes a loooooong time to make. And you'll keep making it over and over, a little bit shorter each time as the loop works through the buffer. The thing is, you don't want to make it. You just want the bit up to the newline, and that's effectively what code sample 2 is doing.

My pitch for a solution. See if you can get rid of the gigabuffer and use `std::getline` directly on the input stream gigabuffer comes from.

```cpp
std::string line;
while (std::getline(inputstream, line)) 
{
    unsigned long tmp = std::stoul(line, &numchars, 16);
    process(tmp);
}
```

If you don't have an input stream, all you get is gigabuffer, [use Artyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63855227/4581301).